# How do you get multiprocessing Pool to not spin up new processes but also not terminate currently running processes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

I am using the Python `multiprocessing.Pool` class in `Python 2.7`. I have a large amount of jobs that can only run in a certain time period of the day. Each job takes some time. I would like to limit the jobs to run at most n parallel at one time.

The Pool functionality works to limit the number of parallel jobs nicely, but it seems to have issues when I am trying to wind down the jobs. When I am at the end of my window I would like the currently running jobs to finish their processing. I would like for no new jobs to start. I have been trying to do this using `Pool.close()`, which does let my running processes finish as desired, but it seems from experimentation that the jobs which were in the queue but not yet started processing will still be submitted for processing even after the Pool is closed.

The other option, `Pool.terminate()` aggressively closes even the running jobs, which goes against desired behaviour.

| Function | Allows running jobs to finish | Prevents new jobs from starting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .terminate() | No | Yes |
| .close() | Yes | No |
| Desired behaviour | Yes | Yes |

Comment: Just a thought, but a simple approach might be to have the beginning of each job check for a signal or event from the main process; once you set that at the end of your run window, any running jobs will continue, because they already checked for the signal when they began, but any new ones started will immediately exit. (there might be a bit of performance hit when a large number of short-lived processes fire up in a short period of time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not be using Python2.7, it has been deprecated for a while now.

You should use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` standard library and call the `.shutdown()` method with the `cancel_futures` flag activated to let the executor finish started jobs but cancel any pending work.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

parallel_jobs = 4  # The pool size
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(parallel_jobs)

future_1 = executor.submit(work_1, argument_1)
...
future_n = executor.submit(work_n, argument_n)

...
# At some point when the time window ends and you need to stop jobs:
executor.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)

# Some futures such as future_n may have  been cancelled here, you can check that:
if future_n.cancelled():
    print("job n has been cancelled")

# Or you can try to get the result while checking for CancelledError:

try:
    result_n = future_n.result()
except CancelledError:
    print("job n hasn't finished in the given time window")
```

Here is an example of cancellation:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed, wait
from time import sleep

# The job to execute concurrently
def foo(i: int) -> str:
    sleep(0.2)
    print(i)
    return f"{i}"

e = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

# Jobs are scheduled concurrently, this call does not block
futures = [e.submit(foo, i) for i in range(100)]

# Shutdown during execution and cancel pending jobs
e.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)

# Gather completed results
results = [f.result() for f in futures if not f.cancelled()]
print(results)
```

If you execute this code you'll see that the 100 scheduled jobs are not all completed, only some are because the executor has been shutdown in between.

Comment: This seems like an extremely useful way of doing this. Unfortunately I don't have 3.x set up on the target machine, and when I try to use it for my Conda env I get glibc errors. Thanks for the option! I'll focus some time on those glibc errors and try this option if I'm able to resolve the issues.

Comment: Somehow the recent version(3.9) started working for me today without changing anything. When I went to run this with cancel_futures=True, though, it kept running new jobs after the pool was closed. Is there a difference if I submit jobs using `.submit` vs. `.map`? Either this also doesn't behave the way I expected or I'm doing something wrong in submitting jobs.

Comment: Yes, `.submit` schedules jobs to run asynchronously (it does not waits the result), so you have to await the future results, while with `.map` the tasks are run concurrently but it waits for all tasks to finish.

Comment: I added detail to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I would like to clarify for future readers to be careful of `.map` since shutting down the pool will not cancel pending jobs created by `.map`.